# how can I parse a given edittext value from one activity to another? the value should overwrite a given textview in the new activity

Tags: android

I am sort of new to android programming. I have a series of `EditText` fields and I want the program to allow a user to input a value into the `EditText` field and whatever value that is input should be transferred to another activity where the value overwrites the content of a textview. How can I do this?

Comment: Use Bundle attached to Intent

Answer (score 1):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(AnotherActivity.KEY_EXTRAS_MESSAGE_AUTHOR, this.myEditText.getText().toString()));
startActivity(intent);
```

in AnotherActivity:

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String KEY_EXTRAS_MESSAGE_AUTHOR= "author";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

String author = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_EXTRAS_MESSAGE_AUTHOR);
```

Comment: the line of code startActivity(intent), isn't this line going to fire up the activity? also, the acctivity that i am passing the edittext value to comes much later on.( there are a series of activitites that are supposed to take place before the final activity where the textview value is to be changed),  wont the line of code" startActivity(intent) cause some problems?. im confused

Comment: In this case you should use `SharedPreferences` to store the text from your `EditText` OR you should pass that value via Bundle thru every activity in chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as shown below:

Define Edit Text in the activity:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Read the value from edit text:

```
String readValue = editText.getText().toString();
```

Create an Intent and pass the value to another activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, anotherActivity.class);
//Passing the string here
intent.putExtra("value", readValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your anotherActivity catch the intent and set the value to edit text:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String result = intent.getStringExtra("value");
```

Define Edit Text in the activity:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
set the text:

editText.setText(result);
```

If you do not want to fire the activity by using startActvity(intent), you can use the following procedure:

Save the edit text value in Shared preferences:

Define Edit Text in the activity:

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Read the value from edit text:

```
 String readValue = editText.getText().toString();
```

Save the value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("value", readValue);
        editor.commit();
```

In another activity use it as shown below

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String result = sharedPreferences.getString("value");
```

Define Edit Text in the activity:

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    set the text:

    editText.setText(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for voting, if this helped you, can you please accept it as an answer also. Thanks.

Comment: the line of code startActivity(intent), isn't this line going to fire up the activity? also, the acctivity that i am passing the edittext value to comes much later on.( there are a series of activitites that are supposed to take place before the final activity where the textview value is to be changed),  wont the line of code" startActivity(intent) cause some problems?. im confused

Comment: If you do not want to fire the activity you can save the value in shared preferences and then use that where ever you need it in another activity, I will update the answer please use that.

Comment: yes it did...thanks alot. but another challenge came up. when I get the value inputed in the edittext, i stored that value in an int variable because I wanted to do some form of calculation with it. here's the code..

Comment: Button nextbutton =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1next); 
  nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     
    double  readValue15= Double.valueOf(edit15watt.getText().toString());
     readValue15= readValue15 * 15;
     final Intent a = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Summary.class);
     a.putExtra("value", readValue15);
     startActivity(a);

Comment: -------------------------------------------------                                                      on the other activity, I tried calling this int variable which I had already used to perform some arithmetic calculation but the intent cannot display the final value of the variable. here's the code

Comment: public class Summary extends ActionBarActivity {
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.summary);
  
  
 int valueone = getIntent().getIntExtra("value",);
 TextView watt15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 watt15.setText("The total power consumed by 15watt bulbs is" +valueone);

Comment: if this helped then please accept it as an answer. Here you are passing an string from that activity and in the other activity you are trying to get int by using intExtra hence you are not getting the value.

Comment: i tried to accept it as an answer but apparently, I need reputation score of 15 and above to do that. but thanks alot. your advice was helpful

Comment: No if you accept it as an answer you will get a reputation of 2, just click the tick mark, move the cursor below the down vote mark you will find that, no need of reputation to do that, to down vote you need 15 reputation please do not do that.

Comment: you can check other answers here you will get an idea.